# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in Android Application

Tags: java, android, jdbc, neo4j, nosuchmethoderror

I'm trying to connect to my Neo4j Server using Java JDBC driver through an Android Application (using Android Studio). It works fine in Eclipse, however here I'm getting an error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`. I have added the JDBC jar file, I was searching and seems that Android is using outdated version of HttpClient. I downloaded the file from: https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/ and added the jar but the error doesn't go away. This is my code and stack trace:

```
Class.forName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection con = null;

        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j://xxx.xxx:7474"); --> This is where error is (name of server hidden for security)


        // Querying
        try(Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("MATCH (n:Manager) RETURN n.Email");
            while (rs.next()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, rs.getString("n.Email"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // System.out.println(rs.getString("n.Email"));
            }
        }
```

The stack trace:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3855)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4470)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18593)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3850)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4470)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18593)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.<init>
            at org.restlet.ext.httpclient.HttpClientHelper.configure(HttpClientHelper.java:275)
            at org.restlet.ext.httpclient.HttpClientHelper.start(HttpClientHelper.java:478)
            at org.restlet.Client.start(Client.java:217)
            at org.restlet.Restlet.handle(Restlet.java:315)
            at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:177)
            at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1136)
            at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleOutbound(ClientResource.java:1225)
            at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1068)
            at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1044)
            at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:950)
            at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.get(ClientResource.java:658)
            at org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.Resources$DiscoveryClientResource.readInformation(Resources.java:131)
            at org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.Resources.getDiscoveryResource(Resources.java:65)
            at org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.Resources.getDiscoveryResource(Resources.java:60)
            at org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jConnection.getDiscoveryResource(Neo4jConnection.java:80)
            at org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jConnection.createExecutor(Neo4jConnection.java:69)
            at org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jConnection.<init>(Neo4jConnection.java:61)
            at org.neo4j.jdbc.Connections$4.doCreate(Connections.java:51)
            at org.neo4j.jdbc.Connections.create(Connections.java:62)
            at org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:64)
            at org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:36)
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:144)
            at computing.gmit.ie.scorerapp.Login.btnLoginClick(Login.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3850)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4470)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18593)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess it has to do with the way you are dynamically loading that class at runtime. If you are running pro-guard and your code is obfuscated this is likely the problem.

Try adding the library to your project and importing the class as you normally would.